# Environment variable not working

Tags: java, environment-variables

I'm trying to setup a PATH environment variable for java. When I setup the variable value as the following, it works perfectly fine while typing "java" in cmd

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
```

But for the following I get error, 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
```

I'm using windows 8. Any idea why the above variable doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide the result of "echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%"?

Comment: @Jermaine, the result is "C:\Program Files (x86)" ... The %ProgramFiles(x86)% works in cmd but it doesn't work when I use it as the variable value

Comment: Did you create another cmd window after setting PATH?

Comment: yes, I created a new cmd window. I'm trying to fix this for 3 hrs

Comment: Then did you use the correct separator(; not :)? or can you paste your full PATH?

Comment: There is no need to use a separator since I removed all other variables except the one for java. Still not working. Could it be a Windows 8 bug?

Comment: If you capture a set of commands that show the problem happening in the cmd window, we might be able to help.  In particular, _how_ are you setting the path?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Finally I reinstalled Java in a different directory other than Program Files

Answer (score 0):

To reduce complexity, I would suggest creating another system environment variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
```

Then in your PATH you can just add:

```
%JAVA_HOME%
```